# How to get session object into a hashmap

Tags: java, spring-boot, object, session, hashmap

I am saving a `HashMap` into a `session` like so:

```
HashMap<Integer, Cart> cart = new HashMap<>();
            cart.put(id, new Cart(product.getName(), product.getPrice(), 1, product.getImage()));
            session.setAttribute("cart", cart);
```

But how am I supposed to get it out of the session back into a `HashMap` ?

I am aware that the session data is stored as an object but do not know how to get it into a `HashMap`

I've tried:

```
HashMap<Integer, Cart> cart = session.getAttribute("cart");
```

But it says `cannot from Object to HashMap`

Comment: Because return type of `getAttribute` is `Object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getAttribute` returns `Object`

```
public Object getAttribute(String name)
```

You can cast Map as,

```
HashMap<Integer, Cart> cart = (HashMap<Integer, Cart>) session.getAttribute("cart");
```

Answer (score 0):

session stores the values as Object. You need to type cast when retrieving from session to the type of object you stored in session.